# Survival Analysis in R and Cox Proportional Hazard Model

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

I am trying to do a coxph model with the following code:

```
coxph.fitR <- coxph(Surv(Survival_test$Recency, Survival_test$Event) ~ Survival_test$Group)
```

My dataset looks as following:
I have a Vector with the times, whether the event occured or not and which Group the individual is associated with. My goal is to find the difference between the two Groups:

```
structure(list(User = 1:10, Recency = c(30L, 9L, 6L, 77L, 5L, 
3L, 46L, 55L, 64L, 328L), Event = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), Group = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", 
"A", "B")), .Names = c("User", "Recency", "Event", "Group"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = structure(list(User = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), Recency = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), Event = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), Group = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("User", "Recency", "Event", "Group"
    )), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

I get the following result and my question: Why do i only get values for the group B and not also for Group A? Or how can i interpret those values?

```
> coxph.fitR
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(Survival_test$Recency, Survival_test$Event) ~ 
    Survival_test$Group)

                       coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z    p
Survival_test$GroupB -0.387     0.679    0.717 -0.54 0.59

Likelihood ratio test=0.29  on 1 df, p=0.591
n= 10, number of events= 10
```

Excuse me if this is a very obvious question!

Comment: Group A is the reference category. Search this site for "reference category" for many answers.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've done this, but I believe what is happening is that group A is your baseline model, and so it is showing the difference between group A and B (which is what you originally asked).

i.e. if group A didn't smoke, and group B did and you were measuring survival of lung cancer what it is showing you is the effects of smoking.

Comment: Is this the same case when there is the category listed but with a value NA and Coefficients:`(1 not defined because of singularities)` ?

Comment: Honestly don't know. My guess with that is that there is only 1 observation in a that category and so you can't draw meaningful results.